# Does lseek()'s SEEK_HOLE behaves as expected?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

According to [`lseek` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) the `SEEK_HOLE` and `SEEK_DATA` are not obliged to do one may think they should do. This is documentation-wise, but reality sometimes differs from documentation. The question is, given recent enough Linux, say, kernel 4.15+, do they (`SEEKHOLE/SEEKDATA`) provide what is expected? Is it could "see" actual holes in files? What happens if I actually write zeroes to some file regions? Would it consider these regions as `DATA`?

Answer (score 2):

A file "hole" is a range of file offsets that hasn't been written to.  Writing zeros does not create a hole, it creates data in the file that happens to be zeroes.  Sparse files have "holes", and when you read from a hole, the file system gives you a block of zeroed memory.  No such zeroes actually exist on the disk.  Usually the "holes" on the disk are represented by some metadata describing the size of the hole.  This is a form of compression.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Comment: As per man page - "Furthermore, a sequence of zeros that actually has been written to the underlying storage may not be reported as a hole.". "May not" means sometimes it may. Am I missing something?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg, well then, perhaps it may.  It's probably dependent on some configuration settings.  The only case I can think of where it would make any sense to do so, is when the file is zeroed at creation.  You should ask the maintainers of your file system code, or go read it yourself.

Comment: I would add that "may not", sounds like standards language.

Comment: hehe, "go read it yourself" should be "go test it yourself" and looks like I definitely will

Comment: I was referring to the code.  The source code is its own documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like it is not working as expected. Here is the code at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d87e87e64bcebc3)

It creates sparse fire checks for holes, data, then it writes data and checks again. Here is the output.

> Seek hole at 0: 0 
> Seek hole at 5 * 1024: 5120 
> Seek data at 0: -1 
> Seek
>   data at 5 * 1024: -1

So far, the output makes sense.
Then I write some data

> File offset set to 5 * 1024: 
>   1024 bytes written to the file

And recheck holes/data.

> Seek hole at 0: 0
>   Seek hole at 5 * 1024: 8192
>   Seek data at 0: 4096
>   Seek data at 5 * 1024: 5120
>   Seek hole at 5 * 1024 + 10: 8192
>   Seek data at 5 * 1024 + 10: 5130

It looks like that the extent information maintained for sparse file is based on my ext4 block size.

According to [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/440255/) article, (at least how I get it) it never worked properly on Linux and I guess, never will. The same article mentions `ioctl`'s `FIEMAP` which has its own problems. So I guess if you want to manage sparse file with granularity less than your block size, stick to your home-made extent management.

Am I missing something?